# Wordpress on Google App Engine Service as subroute

Tags: wordpress, google-app-engine

I am trying to install Wordpress using this tutorial https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/run-wordpress-on-appengine-standard.

I have it deployed, but when I try to have it as "subfolder" `/blog` service of the main domain using `dispatch.yaml`, the site seems to load (e. g. file `/blog/2021/05/27/hello-world/`), but the `css` and `js` files throw `404` error.

E.g. `/blog/wp-includes/css/dist/block-library/style.min.css?ver=5.7.2`.

I have also changed `siteurl` in the database, but that does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your static file handler in app.yaml. Since you are putting your site under a folder (sub folder), calls to your static files start from `/blog/`. This means the handlers for your static file should also start with `/blog/`

Comment: Hi, thx for the tip, this kind of setup seems to work for "non php" pages. But for page like `wp-login.php` there is no handler and I cannot figure out, how it should look like.

Comment: There is a handler. It is in your app.yaml file. The tutorial you pointed to has an app.yaml file and it can be found here - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-tools/blob/master/src/Utils/WordPress/files/app.yaml

Comment: I have figured a workaround for php files, as they are served by `gae-app.php` file and this causes the trouble.